# removing grub and restoring w10 bootloader without access to administrative account in w10

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, multi-boot, grub

I have a dual boot with W10 and debian. Grub is installed in MBR. I would like to remove grup altogether (and even debian) and restore to W10 bootloader. The restriction is that I cannot login to w10 and even if i could, i do not have admin rights. I have full access to debian. Alternatively, an acceptable solution is to change grub such that it boots w10 by default with zero delay.

Comment: This cannot be solved within Windows without Administrator rights.  Is there a reason you are dual booting a system where you don't have elevated rights?  How you modify grub to boot directly into the Windows Boot Loader by default is well documented.  What step of that process are you stuck on?

Comment: @Ramhound Windows is administered by IT department, Linux by me. I know how to modify grub to boot to windows by default, I do not know how to do it without showing the grub window (as i do not want them to know that there is a dual boot, I know, if they wanted, they could find out but if they do not suspect, they won't bother investigate).